# Html Encoding of output in legacy ASP.NET site

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, httprequest

I have a legacy ASP.Net site (recently upgraded to .NET 4.0) which never had Request Validation turned on and it doesn't Html encode any user input at all.

My solution was to turn on request validation and to catch the HttpRequestValidationException in Global.asax and redirect the user to an error page. I don't Html Encode the user input as I'll have to do it in thousands of places. I hope my approach will stop any XSS vectors getting saved into database.

However, in case if there is already any XSS vector stored in database I reckon I should also Html encode all output. Unfortunately I have very limited dev and test resource to successfully achieve this. I came up with a list of changes I need to go through:

1. Search and Replace all <%= %> with <%: %>.
2. Search and Replace all Labels with Literals and add Mode="Encode".
3. Wrap all eval() with HtmlEncode.

My questions are:

1. Is there any simpler way of turning on all output to be automatically Html encoded?
2. Am I missing anything from above list?
3. Any pitfalls I should be careful about?

Thanks.

Comment: You got most of them. Keep in mind, you can't do a total Find/Replace, since probably in some places your binds aren't exclusively user input and maybe error messages with <span> tags or something.

Comment: As well as the other answers, make sure you properly encode any JS output using the Anti-XSS Library: https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=28589.  It might be a good time to integrate it into your site.

Answer (score 0):

> Search and Replace all <%= %> with <%: %>.

Don't forget the <%# and Response.Write which will be harder to replace

> Search and Replace all Labels with Literals and add Mode="Encode".

But you will loose all formatting on the previously generated spans, break the DOM
and the corresponding js/css

You would also have to search all Literals with Mode="PassThrough" and set them to Encode

> Wrap all eval() with HtmlEncode.

Yes, it seems like a subset of the <%# matter above

Also, you could have some custom controls with funky render method

Assuming there is "only" a relational DB as back-end, If I had access to the DB, I would first go on identifying the problematic tables and columns which values contain markup.

I would then :

- cleanup as best as I can those values in DB.
- ensure HtmlEncoding of the corresponding outputs in my pages

I could then go for a basic global replace <%= becoming <%: and sanitize outputs on the long run.